# Vue.js & Tailwind reuse component with different size

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, tailwind-css

I'm starting to play with Vue.js and Tailwindcss. I would like to create a component that scale depending on the container in which it's in. Is there a way to do that easily ?
For instance my current component is the following one :

NowPlaying.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-row flex-grow items-center p-24">
    <TrackImage class="h-64 w-64" :image="image" :blurred="!isPlaying" />
    <div class="ml-10 flex-1">
      <div
        class="uppercase tracking-tight font-extrabold text-5xl text-left text-white break-normal"
      >
        {{ name }}
      </div>
      <div
        class="tracking-tight font-semibold text-3xl text-white text-left w-auto inline-block pb-4"
      >
        {{ artistsList }}
      </div>
      <ProgressBar />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Which is used in the following page:

```
<template>
  <div class="h-screen bg-black">
    <div class="container mx-auto h-full flex flex-col">
      <NowPlaying :class="nowPlayingClasses" />
      <TopTracks v-if="!isPlaying" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

My idea with `nowPlayingClasses` was to dynamically set classes of the `NowPlaying` component to resize it so I can later add a scaling animation without rebuilding my page.
But I can't get how I could do this.

I did try to use the `scale` css transformation, but it keeps the initial component size which is not what I want.